# Exchanging messages between two Ruby scripts

Tags: ruby, linux, event-handling

I have two Ruby scripts: `loop.rb` and `event.rb`. When I run `event.rb` while running a loop in `loop.rb`, the former must catch the latter and change its behaviour.

There are many hacks that I can use; for example, `loop.rb` watches some env-var, and `event.rb` changes it. But I feel it a bit dirty.

What is the right way to send message from one Ruby script to another in Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think best option would be to use ZeroMQ:

https://github.com/zeromq/rbzmq

```
require "zmq"

context = ZMQ::Context.new(1)

puts "Opening connection for READ"
inbound = context.socket(ZMQ::UPSTREAM)
inbound.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:9000")

outbound = context.socket(ZMQ::DOWNSTREAM)
outbound.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:9000")
p outbound.send("Hello World!")
p outbound.send("QUIT")

loop do
  data = inbound.recv
  p data
  break if data == "QUIT"
end
```

Comment: Great, it is what I want!